# Does the position of the detector/observer influence the double slit experiment? At what distance is the result an interference pattern again?

Tags: experimental-physics, interference, double-slit-experiment, observers, quantum-measurements

Does the position of the detector/observer influence the double slit experiment? At what  distance is the result an interference pattern again?

I’m asking this because the detector/observer influences the result of the double slit experiment.

Comment: A "detector" is an absorber. If you put a detector in front of a slit, then you are simply covering up the slit. Having said that, the double slit is not a quantum experiment. You can easily see this in the fact that Planck's constant doesn't play any role in it. The photon statistics simply traces out the classical intensity predicted by Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the detector influences the relative intensities of the waves from the slits. If the detector is much closer to slit A than to slit B, you'll see little interference because the waves from slit A dominate.

Comment: I’m asking this because the detector/observer influences (entangled with the particle? spooky) the result of the double slit experiment

Comment: @midvoor It's really not spooky if you treat the interference with a wave model and the detection with a particle model.